# Select only ONE or NONE of the checkbox inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state

My goal is to have two checkbox items, where the user can only select ONE or select NONE. While one is selected, the other should be **disabled**. I have this so far, but it is **not working** as I expected.

If there is a better way to this overall, please let me know!!

I have a **class component** with the following content:

```
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       aSelected: false,
       bSelected: false
     }
  }

 handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {   
     const { checked, value } = e.target;
    
     console.log( 'checked: ', checked );

     if(value=="a") {
        this.setState( {aSelected: checked}, () =>  {
        console.log('aSelected: ', this.state.aSelected);
        console.log("---")
     });
     }

     if(value=="b") {
        this.setState( {bSelected: checked}, () =>  {
        // console.log('bSelected: ', this.state.bSelected);
        // console.log("---")
     });
     } 
 }
```

Somewhere inside the render return, I have this:

```
<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="a"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   disabled={ (this.state.aSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true} 
</input>

<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="b"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   disabled={ (this.state.bSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true}
</input>
```

Problems I'm having:

1. The `disabled` behavior is NOT matching up with how I detailed it in the first line.
2. `this.state.aSelected` and `this.state.bSelected` always log false no matter how many times I select and unselect the checkbox. The `checked` value is correctly toggled, though. (Below is the ouput for toggling the "a checkbox"):

[image]

Comment: I copied your code and just fixed a syntax  problem (here `aSelected: false;` I replaced `;` with `,`) and everything seems ok

Comment: Hi Saeed, I made a typo on Stack overflow but NOT on my environment. I have a comma in my environment and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @SaeedShamloo, do you mind reposting the answer you had, so that I can view the output on the code snippet?

Comment: Hi @penguin , sure. i did it

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way you can take a look at this question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70759628/disable-checkbox-for-item-that-is-not-defaultchecked. It's a follow up to the question on this page. If not, it's okay.

Comment: let me check it.