# Disable checkbox for item that is not defaultChecked

Tags: reactjs, class, checkbox, default

I have two checkbox items. One of them will be **default selected** upon entry into the page, by props. Depending on which item is selected on default, the **other checkbox item should be disabled** upon entry into the page.

Also, the **user can deselect the default checked item**, in which case, both checkboxes become enabled for selection. When the user then selects one of the two options, the non-selected option will become disabled again.

**What works:** When I deselect the default option and reselect one of the two checkboxes, the disabled behavior works correctly (in that the non-selected option becomes disabled).

**What does not work and need to find a fix for:** When I enter the page, the option that is NOT selected by default needs to be disabled. I need to figure out how to disable the non-selected option upon entry into the page.

I have a **class component** with the following content:

```
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           aSelected: false,
           bSelected: false
         }
      }
  
     handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {   
         const { checked, value } = e.target;

         // NOTE: 'checked' is a boolean

         if(value=="a") {
            this.setState( {aSelected: checked} );
         }

         if(value=="b") {
            this.setState( {bSelected: checked} );
         } 
     }

     // returns default value of each checkbox based on props
     handleDefault = (trueOrFalse, name) => {   
         if(name == "a") { return trueOrFalse; } 
         if(name == "b") { return trueOrFalse; }
     }
```

Somewhere inside the render return, I have this:

```
<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="a"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   disabled={ (this.state.aSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true}
   defaultChecked={this.handleDefault(this.props.selected["a"], "a")}
</input>

<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="b"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   disabled={ (this.state.bSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true}
   defaultChecked={this.handleDefault(this.props.selected["b"])}
</input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are initializing your `aSelected` and `bSelected` states by `false` value, to handle your scenario you can initialize your states by props in the `constructor` of your component, like below example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      aSelected: props.selectedValue == 'a',
      bSelected: props.selectedValue == 'b',
    };
  }

  handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const { checked, value } = e.target;
    if (value == 'a') {
      this.setState({ aSelected: checked });
    }

    if (value == 'b') {
      this.setState({ bSelected: checked });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value="a"
          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
          defaultChecked={this.props.selectedValue == 'a'}
          disabled={
            this.state.aSelected ||
            (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected)
              ? false
              : true
          }
        />

        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value="b"
          defaultChecked={this.props.selectedValue == 'b'}
          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
          disabled={
            this.state.bSelected ||
            (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected)
              ? false
              : true
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App selectedValue='a'/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @penguin does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Btw, in your constructor, I think it should be this.props.selectedValue, not props.selectedValue.

Comment: Could you provide your code on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Hi, it was an external reason and I resolved it. Appreciate your help, tho. Your input here was very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help.